# supremum of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let 
$$l_1=\sup\{2|a|^2+|b|^2;\;\;(a,b)\in \mathbb{C}^2,\;|a|^2+|b|^2=1\},$$
and
$$l_2=\sup\{|a|^2+|a\bar{b}+b\bar{a}|^2;\;\;(a,b)\in \mathbb{C}^2,\;|a|^2+|b|^2=1\}.$$

> It is possible that $l_1=l_2$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $$l_1=\sup\{|a|^2+1; \ |a|^2\leq 1\} = 2$$

For $l_2$, let $a=r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $b=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ then 
$$ |a|^2+ |b|^2=1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad r^2_1+r_2^2 =1$$
and 
$$|a|^2+|a\bar{b}+b\bar{a}|^2= r^2_1+r^2_1r_2^2|e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}+e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}   | \leq r^2_1+2r^2_1r_2^2 $$
so 
\begin{align*} l_2\leq l_3 & = \sup\{r^2_1+2r^2_1r_2^2; \ r_1,r_2\geq 0; \  r^2_1+r_2^2 =1\} \\
& = \sup\{r^2_1+2r^2_1(1-r_1^2); \ 1\geq r_1\geq 0\}
 \end{align*}

So you have to study the real valued function 
$$  x\mapsto x^2+2x^2(1-x^2)-2 $$ 
over $[0,1]$. 
The derivative is $6x-8x^3$ and you will find the maximums at 
$$ x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$
with value $-7/8$.

Finally (since the converse $l_3\leq l_2$ is clear)
$$ l_2=l_3= 2-\frac{7}{8}<l_1$$

Comment: @kingW3 : yes, I made a mistake ; but I am typing the solution now.

Comment: I don't understand if  $l_1=l_2$  or not

Comment: @Student: not. $l_2<l_1$, see my edit.